# Как дебажить typescript в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: javascript, отладка, typescript

Есть обычный js-дебаггер который подключается к браузеру через экстеншен, но он не работает с typescript файлами, бряки бесполезны. Мало того, дебаггер в хроме не дебажит сгенеренные js-файлы, потому что они грузятся динамически с помощью systemJS.

Объясните мне пожалуйста, как дебажить ts в IntelliJ IDEA? И почему динамически загруженные js не дабажутся даже в браузере?

Comment: Конечно всякое бывает, но у JetBrains шикарные доки https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/debugging-typescript.html и для идеи https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugging-typescript.html

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев у меня не дебажатся эти файлы т.к. js-файлы подгружаются динамически с помощью systemJS. Я в этом и не могу разобраться, я же написал об этом!

Comment: тогда печальные известия :) https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1305